# Why does the compiler not optimize this initialization?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Consider the following C code:

```
extern void foo(int* ip);

void myfunc(void)
{
    int arr[15] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 42;
    }

    foo(arr);
}
```

I tried with gcc and clang, with `-O3` and `-Os`. In all cases the compiled assembly writes all 15 zeroes before overwriting 10 of them with 42.

I suppose it could just be that no optimization has been written for this case yet, but it seems like a fairly obvious and common case to me. Is there something that prevents the optimization?

I am on x86-32 Linux and used these commands:

```
gcc -std=c99 -S -O3 hello.c
clang -std=c99 -S -O3 hello.c
```

Comment: It's always possible to defeat the compiler by writing idiotic code - you'd need an infinitely complex compiler to handle all possible inefficiencies that an inept programmer might introduce.

Comment: This is a deliberately simplified example, but I think it is fairly common to first zero-initialize a struct and then write to some of the fields.

Comment: Do you think the compiler should generate code to initialise only elements `[10..14]`, on the basis that you are about to set elements `[0..9]`?

Comment: Does the generated code change if you initialize the elements individually rather than in a loop? @WeatherVane a more likely optimization would be to initialize *all* the elements at the same time with the proper contents.

Comment: Why was this question out on hold? I am not asking for any opinions.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, same result. I also tried with a struct and a designated initializer where I only set some of the elements. That also produces a full zero-out followed by individual writes.

Comment: @TorKlingberg Any answer to this question would probably be based on an individual opinion of why gcc/clang don't use this optimization.

Comment: @TorKlingberg I suppose this *is* opinion: you aren't asking why your code failed, but how it could have been better.

Comment: array is a very conservative data type i think. if you announce `int arr[100000000];` are you expecting compiler to keep track of all the elements?

Comment: You might make a feature request on [GCC bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Comment: Really?  *why* or *why not* a compiler does or does not do something is very subjective in a case like this.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the practical case where such an optimization would bring significant performance improvement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a very scientific explanation, but just an intuition (however, I do happen to know *some* of the internals of GCC).

To reliably do the optimization that you want, the compiler would have to manage *sub-arrays* or *slices*. Then it is becoming very complex and error-prone. A compiler optimizing that much is likely to consume a lot of memory (for the symbolic representations of sub-arrays) and a lot of compiler time. This is usually not worth the effort (which would be better spent inside the compiler to optimize loops).

BTW, GCC has a plugin framework and the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a lispy domain specific language to extend GCC, and I am the main author of MELT). So you could try to add a new optimization pass (thru a MELT extension or some C++ plugin) doing the work. You'll soon realize that your pass would be either extraordinarily specific or would require handling a big lot of GCC internal representations, and is likely to blow up compilation time and memory for very few gains.

Notice that both GCC and Clang are cleverly unrolling the two loops (and that matters a lot performance-wise).

BTW, the [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (a static analyzer for C programs developed by colleagues) value analyzer seems able to infer good properties about your `arr`

So, feel free to add that optimization to GCC. If you don't know (or don't have the time - many months or years) how to add it, feel free to pay a company or an organization able to enhance GCC for your needs. It is probably a million euro (or US dollars) / 3 years project to get that optimization working on interesting cases.

<sup>If you are serious about spending such amount of money, contact me by email.</sup>

A compiler which has such optimization would need some heuristics to disable them (e.g. if `arr` was a million-member array, and you was coding some [sieve of Erasthothenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), it is probably not worth the compiler effort to keep all the unions of sub-slices of composite indexes at compile-time).

BTW, would you accept a twenty-times slower optimizing compiler (slower at compile time) for a gain (probably of a fraction of percent at run-time) which happens rarely in practice and is not very important? At last, I don't believe that this is a *common case* for optimizations. YMMV.

You might be perhaps interested by source to source transformers like [PIPS4U](http://pips4u.org/)

Comment: Good point. However, the MELT part has sincerely very little to do with the question and, imho, should be omitted.

Comment: I disagree. MELT is designed to write such optimizations more quickly (because it is a bit higher level than the C++ language used inside GCC). But even with MELT, it is a big job.

Comment: That's great to hear. But the OP did not ask you how to implement that; (s)he asked you *why* it was not being optimized.

Comment: @black I think your questions show that the discussion is inherently opinion-based